# Applying complex code with multi-tasks to bruteforce logic

Tags: c#, security, passwords, multitasking, brute-force

I've recently made a simple bruteforcer. Everything goes properly as I've expected, but not when I try to make everything multi-tasked.

This is the current code I have:

```
private static void startBruteForce(int keyLength)
    {
    var keyChars = createCharArray(keyLength, charactersToTest[0]);

    var indexOfLastChar = keyLength - 1;
    createNewKey(0, keyChars, keyLength, indexOfLastChar);
}

private static char[] createCharArray(int length, char defaultChar)
{
    return (from c in new char[length] select defaultChar).ToArray();
}

private static void createNewKey(int currentCharPosition, char[] keyChars, int keyLength, int indexOfLastChar)
{
    var nextCharPosition = currentCharPosition + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < charactersToTestLength; i++)
    {
        keyChars[currentCharPosition] = charactersToTest[i];

        if (currentCharPosition < indexOfLastChar)
        {
            createNewKey(nextCharPosition, keyChars, keyLength, indexOfLastChar);
        }
        else
        {

            computedKeys++;

            Console.WriteLine(new string(keyChars));
            if (new string(keyChars) == "hola")
            {
                if (!isMatched)
                {
                    isMatched = true;
                    result = new string(keyChars);
                }
            }
        }
        if (isMatched) return;
    }
}
```

my current code to call the bruteforcer:

```
       var estimatedPasswordLength = 3;

        while (!isMatched)
        {
            estimatedPasswordLength++;
            startBruteForce(estimatedPasswordLength);
        }
```

these are the chars I use to combine the password to test:

```
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z','A','B','C','D','E',
'F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R',
'S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','1','2','3','4','5',
'6','7','8','9','0','!','$','#','@','-'
```

To get the password `hola` I must to wait most likely ~10 mins. So to reduce the minutes to wait, I'm trying to split the work like this using multiple tasks, and so maybe doing this

```
estimatedPasswordLength++;
startBruteForce(estimatedPasswordLength);
```

synchronously without checking the same password at the time...

I appreciate any suggestion - how would I do it?

EDIT:

Regarding to @Cicero suggestion, this is what I tried:

```
    Parallel.For(0, 4, i => // what should 0 and 4 be?
     {
                 if (isMatched) return;
                  Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => startBruteForce(estimatedPasswordLength));
                  estimatedPasswordLength++;
      });
```

but length is now disproportionate, I get writed on the console strings like:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaac
```

while `estimatedPasswordLength` would be 4. How can I get a solution to make this with a proportionate length?

Comment: You could try and put it inside a `Parallel.For` instead of the regular for-loop. [Parallel For-Loop Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Cicero thank you for your advice. So that parallel for-loops would be pretty useful to run instructions synchronously in for loops and in different threads. Could you make a concrete example of using it?

Comment: No problem. Yes it would be useful. If you click on the Parallel For-Loop Example link in my first comment you can see an example of it, from MSDN.

Comment: @Cicero could you see the new edit of the OP? I'm so sorry for the bad code formatting.